# Is this an OK sentence? "I will continue to seek for opportunities to improve myself as a teacher, and for the school I belong to."

Tags: sentence

Is this an OK sentence?

"I will continue to seek for opportunities to improve myself as a teacher, and for the school I belong to."

A little awkward but I dont know how to better it.

Comment: "I will continue to seek opportunities to better my school as an institution and to improve myself as a teacher."

Comment: I will continue to seek for opportunities to improve myself as a teacher, and to improve the school which I serve.

Comment: To think about the problem, consider that the second clause is an "and for" which means it must parallel a "for" in the first part.  The only *for* you have in the first part is "seek for" so that means you are saying: "I will seek for opportunities" and "I will seek for the school I belong to"  (hopefully the school you belong to is not lost ;-))

Comment: "Seek" roughly means "search for"; the "for" is built in. Also, removing the "for"s, the sentence says you're looking for opportunities to improve yourself, and that you're also trying to find the school.

Comment: Thanks guys.  How about this one: 

I will continue to seek opportunities to improve myself as a teacher, through which bettering my school as an institution.

Comment: I will continue to seek opportunities to improve my school as an institution and me as a teacher. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually, if you just remove both "for"s the sentence is perfectly fine and means what you want; though it can still mean you're trying to find the school, common sense will automatically rule that out. Minimal necessary change.

Comment: `I will continue to seek opportunities to improve myself as a teacher, through which bettering my school as an institution.` The last part of that is quite awkward. Something like this would be better: `I will continue to seek opportunities to improve myself as a teacher, thereby bettering my school as an institution.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is identifying the parallel construction in your sentence:

> "I will continue to seek for opportunities to improve myself as a teacher, and for the school I belong to."

You should be able to construct a sentence with each half and have it be well-formed, like so:

> - I will continue to seek opportunities to improve myself as a teacher.
> - I will continue to seek opportunities to improve the school I belong to.

(Note that, as highlighted in the comments above, you don't need to include the "for" after "seek".)

Now we see that the parallelism is in "*to improve...and...*". This gives us:

> I will continue to seek opportunities to improve myself as a teacher and the school I belong to.

I agree with the comments that there are better ways to phrase this, but at least this is grammatical and makes sense. If you wanted to take it to the next step, have your segments before and after the conjunction match more closely in structure.  For example:

> I will continue to seek opportunities to improve myself as a teacher and this school as an institution.

This works better because it allows for the parallelism in "[object] as a [object]":

> - myself as a teacher
> - this school as an institution